# if statements that can alter a layout

Tags: conditionals, template-layouts

Im working on a project where there are two divs next too each other (not worried about the styling for now) but my question is the following.

div 1  |  div 2

if there's  no channels fields in div 2 hide the div and make div 100%. i tried adding the if statements before the div and also tried the if results == statement, nothing changed.

Anyone who has experienced this issue and solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming 2 fields firstname and lastname...

```
<div class="{if lastname}half{if:else}full{/if}">
  {firstname}
</div>
{if lastname}
  <div class="half">
    {lastname}
  </div>
{/if}
```

Or if either field could be missing/empty...

```
{if firstname}
  <div class="{if lastname}half{if:else}full{/if}">
    {firstname}
  </div>
{/if}
{if lastname}
  <div class="{if firstname}half{if:else}full{/if}">
    {lastname}
  </div>
{/if}
```

Comment: will definitely try this out peter.